# A question in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

let A be an $m\times n$ matrix with real coefficients, show there exists a unique $n\times m$ matrix B such that $(Ax) \cdot y=x\cdot (By)$ for all column vectors $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and $y \in \Bbb R^m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$(Ax) \cdot y=(Ax)^T y=x^TA^Ty=x\cdot(A^Ty)$$
so 
$$(Ax) \cdot y=x\cdot (By)\iff B=A^T$$